# How do I submit a user registration form in code?

Tags: forms, 8

I have tried to save registration data in a controller.

```
$values = \Drupal::request()->request->all();

     $formBuilder = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder');
     $form = $formBuilder->getForm(User::create(array()), 'register', array());
    $formObject = new RegisterForm(\Drupal::entityManager(),
                    \Drupal::languageManager(), \Drupal::service('entity.query'));

     $form_state = (new FormState())->setValues($values);
                //$formObject->form($form,$form_state);
     $entity = $formObject->buildEntity($form,$form_state);
     $formObject->setEntity($entity);
     $formObject->form($form,$form_state);
     $formObject->submitForm($form,$form_state);
     $formObject->save($form,$form_state);
```

Above code produces this error:

> Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in /home/vagrant/www/drupal8/drupal-8.0.1/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityForm.php on line

It seems I need to inject an "entity" before `buildEntity()`.

How did Drupal 8 manage to create a new user? Maybe the container injected that entity some where, but I am unable to find it.

Comment: Do you really want to programmatically submit a form or you just want to create new user?

Comment: @IvanJaros, I just want to create a new user.But submit a form allows the new user to go through all default Drupal actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'm using for creating users. You can just use the entity_create() part.

```
/**
 * Creates a new user account.
 * This function makes sure the account has a unique and valid user name.
 * The only case where the account creation can fail is if the e-mail
 * address is malformed or already taken.
 *
 * @param string $mail
 *   The e-mail address of the new account.
 * @param string $name
 *   The optional login name for the new account.
 *   If no value is provided, the name is derived form the email address.
 * @param string $password
 *   The password for the new account. If empty, random password will be created.
 * @param int $status
 *   The optional status for the new account.
 * @param array $roles
 *   The optional list os user role IDs.
 *
 * @return \Drupal\user\Entity\User
 *   Returns new user object.
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 *   If the email address is not valid an InvalidArgumentException is thrown.
 * @throws \Exception
 *   If new unique user could not be created an exception is thrown.
 */
function mymodule_create_user($mail, $name = NULL, $password = NULL, $status = 1, array $roles = []) {
  // Make sure we have the user name.
  // If not, use the e-mail address and remove unwanted characters.
  // If the user name is provided it will be used as is.
  if (empty($name)) {
    $name = preg_replace("\W|_", '', $mail);
  }

  // Validate the e-mail address first.
  if (!\Drupal::service('email.validator')->isValid($mail)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid e-mail address.');
  }

  // Create password if it was not provided.
  $password = $password ? $password : user_password();

  // Try 20 unique user names before giving up.
  $run = 0;
  while ($run <= 20) {
    /** @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user */
    $user = entity_create('user', [
      'name' => $run == 0 ? $name : ($name . $run),
      'pass' => $password,
      'mail' => $mail,
      'init' => $mail,
      'status' => $status,
      'roles' => $roles
    ]);

    // Validate the object.
    $errors = $user->validate();

    if ($errors->count() == 0) {
      $user->save();
      return $user;
    } else {
      $run++;
    }
  }

  throw new \Exception('Couldn\'t create unique user within given loop limit.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to create new user, it is easy as you create the user object and fill it and save it:

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();
$user->setPassword($values->getValue('pass'));
$user->enforceIsNew();
$user->setEmail($values->getValue('mail'));
$user->setUsername($values->getValue('name'));
$user->activate();
$user->save();
```

but in my case for example I wanted drupal to do other stuff like send welcome email...etc, so what i did, instead of last step ( $user->save() ):

```
$formObject = new RegisterForm($this->entityManager, $this->languageManager, $this->entityQuery);
$formObject->setEntity($user);
$formObject->save($form,$form_state); // $form and $form_state can be created like you did.
// if you want to get the newly created user
$user = $formObject->getEntity();
```

on the other hand I have tried to get your code working, and the following was the outcome code:

```
$formObject = $this->entityManager->getFormObject('user','register');
$formObject->setEntity($user);
$formStateObject = (new FormState())->setFormObject($formObject);
$form = [];
$form = $formObject->buildForm($form,$formStateObject);
$formObject->validateForm($form,$formStateObject);
$formObject->submitForm($form,$formStateObject);
$formObject->save($form,$formStateObject);
```

Hope that helps.