# How I can create a user programatically using user registration form?

Tags: forms, users, 8, entities

How I can create a user programatically in drupal 8. I am using the following code to generate user registration form.

```
$account = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('user')->create([]);
$form = $this->entityFormBuilder->getForm($account, 'register');
```

and form_sate values using the following code.

```
$form_state = (new FormState())->setValues(['name' => 'user1', 'pass' => 'pass']);
```

Now how can submit this form using the above form_state values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically create new user with custom fields?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69694/how-to-programmatically-create-new-user-with-custom-fields)

Comment: please before ask a new question search for it, some question really are very popular .

Comment: And also this "http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/create-a-user-programmatically-and-give-him-a-role" can help you.

Comment: I'm using REST API for creating user and I want to get all the error messages so I think I can't use the normal user_save here.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186760/how-do-i-submit-a-user-registration-form-in-code  - This one is near to my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you needn't use the registration form as you have mentioned. You can use the following code to create a new user:

```
if (!user_load_by_mail('email_id')) {
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();

  //Mandatory settings
  $user->setPassword('your_password');
  $user->enforceIsNew();
  $user->setEmail('email_id');
  $user->setUsername('user_name'); //This username must be unique and accepts only a-Z,0-9, - _ @ .

  //Optional settings
  $user->set("init", 'email');
  $user->set("langcode", $language);
  $user->set("preferred_langcode", $language);
  $user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $language);
  //$user->set("setting_name", 'setting_value');
  $user->activate();

  //Save user
  $result = $user->save();
}
```

You can ensure that an user with same email id doesn't exist using `user_load_by_mail()`, and then proceed with the user creation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here how I can get an error message if a user exist with same email Id in database?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the error message, instead you can check if user exists with same email id and then proceed with account creation. I have updated my answer, kindly check it. Accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of submitting it as a form so that I can get error messages in "$errors = $form_state->getErrors();".